# How can I assign a converted date to a variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

How can I get a converted date time assigned to a variable?

When I run the following query in SQL Server Mgmt Studio, this returns what I want:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(15), CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME), 100)
```

I need to assign to a variable:  something like...

```
DECLARE @mytime AS VARCHAR;

SET @mytime = SELECT CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME),100) --incorrect syntax
SELECT @mytime
```

Comment: Just missing parens to make it a (scalar) sub query.

Comment: Oh my.  I know I was asking a "101-type" of question.  I was driving me a bit crazy.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

*Never* use `VARCHAR` without a length in SQL Server.  In your case, it defaults to a single character.

Then you can use `SET` with a subquery, `SELECT`, or `DECLARE` to assign the value:

```
DECLARE @mytime AS VARCHAR(15);

SET @mytime = (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME),100) );
```

Or:

```
SELECT @mytime = CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME),100);
```

Or:

```
DECLARE @mytime AS VARCHAR(15) = ( SELECT CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME), 100) );
```

Comment: That explains a lot.  I was getting a single character back and didn't realize why.  Humbled, yet happy!

Answer (score 0):

Use `SELECT` :

```
SELECT @mytime = CONVERT(varchar(15), CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME), 100) 

SELECT @mytime
```

Note :

You need to define the length of variable, otherwise data type without length will accept only one character.

```
DECLARE @mytime AS VARCHAR(15)
```